# Validation framework

Tags: java

In an interview my friend was asked to design a validation framework, can any one give me idea how to design a efficient framework

Our approach was 
an interface having all method
and class implementaion of all methods

Comment: What is being validated and against what? I can think of all sorts of validation from pattern matching to business rules engines here, could you add a bit more detail, please.

Comment: Sorry for not metioning all details,
i was talking abt validation on forms like name ,mail ids, number so we need to create a generalize framework for doing all these.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your approach, it sounds quite vague to me.

I would go with an annotation-based approach. Different classes of validations with specific parameters can be defined in an enum, then linked to specific properties via annotations.

```
public enum Validation {
    NUMERIC,
    TWO_DECIMAL_PLACES,
    ...;
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    ...
    Validation[] validation() default { };
    ...
}

...
@MyAnnotation(
        ...
        validation = { Validation.NUMERIC, Validation.TWO_DECIMAL_PLACES })
public BigDecimal getCharge() {
    return Charge;
}
```

At runtime, the annotations can be processed using bean introspection, with [`PropertyDescriptor`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyDescriptor.html) and [`Method.getAnnotation()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)).

I have recently implemented a simple version of this in our own project, but there are several robust examples around (possibly with different implementation), e.g. in Hibernate and Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Peter. Here's a [nice introduction](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-bean-validation-framework.html) to the annotation-based approach using Spring. There's also [JSR303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) if you're interested.